# How to handle time based relationships in ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's assume that I have two models `user` and `post`. One `user` can have multiple `post`and each `post` belongs to one `user`. On particular pages I would like to display `post` based on date, usually only today's posts. **How should I design relationship?**

I could create method in controllers like

```
App.ProfileController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
     getPostsForToday: (->
          @store.all('posts').filterProperty('date', '2014-10-17')
```

but it seems to me that I should put this logic into model

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
     todayPosts: (->
          DS.hasMany("posts").filterProperty('date', '2014-10-17') //something likes this
```

however in this way I can't dynamically change date, can I? What are best strategies to handle relationship based on date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the thing to do would be to use an `ArrayController`, this has sorting built in, and filter the results going into in on your route.

ArrayController:

```
App.TodaysPostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortBy: 'date'
});
```

Controller:

```
App.ProfileController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['todaysPosts'],
    todaysPosts: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.todaysPosts'),
});
```

Route:

```
App.ProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
         // perform default functions
         this._super(controller, model);

         this.store.findAll('post');

         var $this = this;
         var today = '2014-10-17';

         // this will updated whenever any of the posts models change
         this.store.filter('post', { 'date': today }, function(post) {
             return post.get('date');
         })
         .then(function(todaysPosts) {
             $this.controllerFor('todaysPosts').set('model', todaysPosts);
         });
    }
});
```

Info on array controller http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html

Info on store filtering http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter